Snowflake scirpting to run INSERT statement
I am trying to sue Snowflake Scripting to run an insert statement.  I can get it to return a value from a query but not run the statement.
create or replace table ccb_test as
select
1 as value,
sysdate() as ETL_TS;

SET reload_type = 'PARTIAL'


BEGIN
  LET reload := $reload_type;
  IF (reload = 'PARTIAL') THEN
    RETURN ( INSERT into ccb_test select 2 as value, sysdate() as ETL_DATE);
  ELSE
    RETURN (SELECT 'Reload is set to FULL, no merge action needed.' AS message);
  END IF;
END;


I have tried multiple versions of this but only get it to run if I query a statement with one returned value but not an update, insert, or create statement
BEGIN
  LET reload := $reload_type;
  IF (reload = 'PARTIAL') THEN
    RETURN (SELECT 'Reload is set to PARTIAL, merging.' AS message);
  ELSE
    RETURN (SELECT 'Reload is set to FULL, no merge action needed.' AS message);
  END IF;
END;



ok I think this is it.
BEGIN
  IF ($reload_type= 'PARTIAL') THEN
      INSERT into ccb_test select 2 as value, sysdate() as ETL_DATE;
      RETURN 'Reload is set to PARTIAL, merging.';
  ELSE
    RETURN 'Reload is set to FULL, no merge action needed.';
  END IF;
END;


You can accept your answer as the correct one, to indicate to others that this question is done.
